# Compiler thinks a borrow is alive when it isn't

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I've got this code of an arena where allocation gives you an index and you use the same index to get the object later.

```rust
struct Node<'a>(i32, Option<&'a Node<'a>>);

struct Arena<'a>(Vec<Node<'a>>);

impl<'a> Arena<'a> {
    fn alloc(&'a mut self, node: Node<'a>) -> usize {
        let index = self.0.len();
        self.0.push(node);
        index
    }
    fn get(&'a mut self, index: usize) -> &'a mut Node<'a> {
        &mut self.0[index]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut arena = Arena(vec![]);
    let x = arena.alloc(Node(1, None));
    println!("{}", arena.get(x).0)
}
```

`self` is using lifetime `'a` because rust gives another error otherwise:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
```

The return value of alloc is just a `usize` so the borrow of self should be temporary.
However, for some reason, when I call `arena.get` in the `println`, rust thinks arena is still mutably borrowed and gives me this error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `arena` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:19:20
   |
18 |     let x = arena.alloc(Node(1, None));
   |             ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
19 |     println!("{}", arena.get(x).0)
   |                    ^^^^^
   |                    |
   |                    second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                    first borrow later used here
```

So why is this happening?

Note: I know I can use indices in Option and forget about this issue, but I still want to know why rust think arena is mutably borrowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's what you are telling the compiler. Two steps:

In the line

```
fn alloc(&'a mut self, node: Node<'a>) -> usize
```

there is some lifetime `'a` for `Node`; also, you are telling the compiler that the mutable reference `&mut self` will have the same lifetime `'a`, via `&'a mut self`. That is, the `&mut self` reference will live for as long as the lifetime-parameter of `Node`.

Second, in the line `arena.alloc(Node(1, None))`, the literal instance of `Node` you are creating has no lifetime shorter than `'static`, so it's a `Node<'static>`. This means `arena` is a `Arena<'static>`.

Where it all goes wrong is when these two combine: Since you declared `&mut self` to have the same lifetime as `Node`, the compiler has to deduce that the `&mut self` is a `&'static mut self`, because `'a` is `'static`. So, once the first borrow occurs in `main`, no further borrows are *ever* allowed and you are officially stuck.

AFAICS there is no need for those lifetime annotations anyway. If you change the signatures to simply

```
fn alloc(&mut self, node: Node<'a>) -> usize {
fn get(&mut self, index: usize) -> &mut Node<'a> {
```

you example compiles, as the compiler is free to assign lifetimes shorter than whatever `Node` carries to the borrow of `Arena`.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation. Do you know if there's any way to make the compiler spit out the lifetimes it has inferred for the parameters?

Comment: Not as far as I can see. But as a general rule of thumb: You are hardly ever required to specify explicit lifetimes for the receiver. Where it went wrong was when you tried to fix the first error (as mentioned), which more often than not causes your code to only ever be valid for `'static` lifetime; this is also a common source for errors where the compiler requires `'static` but you don't know why.